# Game Loop: Best way to limit the fps?

Tags: game-loop, first-person-shooter

My game-loop looks like this:

```
        public void run() {
            init();

            final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
            double ns = 1000000000.0 / amountOfTicks;
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            long now = 0;
            double delta = 0;
            int tickCount = 0;
            int renderCount = 0;

            while(running) {

                now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;

                if(delta >= 1) {
                    tick();
                    tickCount++;
                    delta--;
                    render();
                    renderCount++;
                }


                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000) {
                    time += 1000;
                    System.out.println(tickCount + " Ticks, " + renderCount + " FPS");
                    tickCount = 0;
                    renderCount = 0;
                }


            }
            stop();

        }
```

In the variable "amountOfTicks" i can set how many ticks i want per second. The amountOfTicks are here the same as the fps which i have. With this solution my console prints "60Ticks, 60 FPS", but the problem is, that the CPU-performance with this method is too low. I have only 60 Ticks and only 60 FPS, but the whole while-loop is still running through as fast as my pc can.

The only thing how i can improve the cpu-performance is, if i let the thread for 1ms or so sleeping. But is this solution not dirty? This solution will maybe work on my (relative good pc), but on a other with with less CPU-performance the 1ms sleep maybe are waste, because of this the game maybe can not reach the 60FPS of this?

Comment: [Obligatory link to *Fix your timestep!*](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) :D

Comment: You need to draw statistics of the users' cpu performance. If `time passed < expected_time`... `sleep expected_time - time_passed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this, one would be a *variable timestep*, with that the game would seem consistent, regardless how fast the computer of the player is.

The other way would be a *fixed timestep*, there you will know how long each single timestep would be, also regardless how fast the computer is.

For more information on Game loops you can look at [this site](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/game-loops/24220/view.html).

Here are some examples:

**Variable timestep**

```
public void gameLoop()
{
   long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
   final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
   final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;   

   // keep looping round til the game ends
   while (gameRunning)
   {
      // work out how long its been since the last update, this
      // will be used to calculate how far the entities should
      // move this loop
      long now = System.nanoTime();
      long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
      lastLoopTime = now;
      double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

      // update the frame counter
      lastFpsTime += updateLength;
      fps++;

      // update our FPS counter if a second has passed since
      // we last recorded
      if (lastFpsTime >= 1000000000)
      {
         System.out.println("(FPS: "+fps+")");
         lastFpsTime = 0;
         fps = 0;
      }

      // update the game logic
      doGameUpdates(delta);

      // draw everyting
      render();

      // we want each frame to take 10 milliseconds, to do this
      // we've recorded when we started the frame. We add 10 milliseconds
      // to this and then factor in the current time to give 
      // us our final value to wait for
      // remember this is in ms, whereas our lastLoopTime etc. vars are in ns.
      try{Thread.sleep( (lastLoopTime-System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME)/1000000 )};
   }
}
```

**Fixed timestep**

```
private void gameLoop()
{
   //This value would probably be stored elsewhere.
   final double GAME_HERTZ = 30.0;
   //Calculate how many ns each frame should take for our target game hertz.
   final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
   //At the very most we will update the game this many times before a new render.
   //If you're worried about visual hitches more than perfect timing, set this to 1.
   final int MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER = 5;
   //We will need the last update time.
   double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
   //Store the last time we rendered.
   double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

   //If we are able to get as high as this FPS, don't render again.
   final double TARGET_FPS = 60;
   final double TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;

   //Simple way of finding FPS.
   int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

   while (running)
   {
      double now = System.nanoTime();
      int updateCount = 0;

      if (!paused)
      {
         //Do as many game updates as we need to, potentially playing catchup.
         while( now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES && updateCount < MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER )
         {
            updateGame();
            lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
            updateCount++;
         }

         //If for some reason an update takes forever, we don't want to do an insane number of catchups.
         //If you were doing some sort of game that needed to keep EXACT time, you would get rid of this.
         if ( now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
         {
            lastUpdateTime = now - TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
         }

         //Render. To do so, we need to calculate interpolation for a smooth render.
         float interpolation = Math.min(1.0f, (float) ((now - lastUpdateTime) / TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) );
         drawGame(interpolation);
         lastRenderTime = now;

         //Update the frames we got.
         int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
         if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime)
         {
            System.out.println("NEW SECOND " + thisSecond + " " + frameCount);
            fps = frameCount;
            frameCount = 0;
            lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
         }

         //Yield until it has been at least the target time between renders. This saves the CPU from hogging.
         while ( now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
         {
            Thread.yield();

            //This stops the app from consuming all your CPU. It makes this slightly less accurate, but is worth it.
            //You can remove this line and it will still work (better), your CPU just climbs on certain OSes.
            //FYI on some OS's this can cause pretty bad stuttering.
            try {Thread.sleep(1);} catch(Exception e) {} 

            now = System.nanoTime();
         }
      }
   }
}
```